# Vim "No Swap File"

Tags: vim

Typing `:w` fails with `No Swap File`, but only intermittently.

The status line says `No Swap File`, and the save does not happen. I have to run `:w` again, one or more times, before it finally punches through the error and actually saves.

It's infuriating because it's very easy to miss it when the save fails. I'll hit `:w`, it'll fail, I won't notice. I'll go to run my code and it'll still be the old version. I'll be confused about why I'm not seeing my code changes, and then I'll have to go back and `:w` a few more times for it to actually save.

I have this in my .vimrc:

```
set nobackup
set noswapfile
```

When I do `:echo &swapfile` in my editing buffers it shows `0`.

How do I fix this? `:w` fails with `No Swap File`, but only intermittently.

Comment: Is that the full error message?

Comment: It appears so. The status line where the file name and line number usually display just says `No Swap File.` It's not a big huge stack dump of any kind, just those 3 words.

Comment: The only place in the vim sources where I can find that message is in the `:swapname` command, but it is spelled `No swap file`, not `No Swap File` (and it is not an error). Do you have a custom autocommand that runs on save?

Comment: It looks like you found it. It does indeed say `No swap file.` I had the casing incorrect in my post. Here's a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/sMeWxvv.png

Comment: @melpomene I just realized that I forgot to answer your question about autocmds. I don't believe I have any. I checked my config files and nothing came up. I do have autocmds, but not for file save. I scanned through the output of `:autocmd` as well, and I didn't find anything. But the output there is tremendously long. I'm up for trying other search methods if you could give me a way conclusively check for write autocmds. But I think the answer will probably be "no write autocmds present."

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003

Comment: I know this won't help you, but I wonder: what is the use case for having neither swap file nor backup? I can't imagine not wanting them myself, so I'd like to know what workflow or situation brought you to want those settings.

Comment: Update: This was all due to the MacBook Pro butterfly keyboard, which is shit. It often fails to register keys, registers keys twice even before the repeat timeout, and is prone to type-o's for touch typists due to the lack of tactile feedback. These shitty input errors were causing this problem. I have `ss` bound to `:`, so when I want to save a file I type `ssw<CR>`. That would sometimes register as `sssw<CR>` instead, which would run `:sw`. Changing the repeat timeout in Vim or in the OS X control panel doesn't fix it. The butterfly keyboard is just shit and has its own mind sometimes.

Comment: @kenorb Done! Question updated to remove the answer. Answer posted as an actual answer. Haven't used SO in forever, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was all due to the MacBook Pro butterfly keyboard, which is just shit. It often fails to register keys, registers keys twice even before the repeat timeout, and is prone to type-o's for touch typists due to the lack of tactile feedback. These shitty input errors were causing this problem. In normal mode I have `ss` bound to `:`, so when I want to save a file I type `ssw<CR>`. That would sometimes register as `sssw<CR>` instead, which would run `:sw` (which is `Show Swap File Name`). Changing the repeat timeout in Vim or in the OS X control panel doesn't fix it. The butterfly keyboard is just garbage and actively fights against you when you're typing.